# How to rotate and lock the rotation of a SCNNode by degrees?

Tags: swift, rotation, scenekit, degrees, radians

I need to rotate a model that can be freely rotated, to exact degrees, regardless of how many times it's been rotated.

I have a UIPanGestureRecognizer that is rotating freely a 3D model around the Y axis. However I'm struggling to get it to lock to a integer degree when panning is stopped, and I'm struggling with being able to know it's rotation in degrees from 0-359.

```swift
let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)

var newAngleY = Double(translation.x) * (Double.pi) / 180.0
newAngleY += self.currentAngle

self.shipNode?.eulerAngles.y = Float(newAngleY)

if (recognizer.state == .ended)
{
   self.currentAngle = newAngleY
}
```

It rotates freely, but all attempts for locking to the closest exact degree, and being able to 'know' it's rotational degree in a value from 0-359.

I know that:

```
let degrees = newAngleY * ( 180 / Double.pi)
```

And I know that if degrees > 360 then -= 360 (pseudo code)

However, whilst the UIPanGestureRecognizer is doing it's thing, these checks seem to fail and I don't know why. Is it because when it's still being panned, you can't edit the private properties of the ViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the value while the gesture is occurring.

Quite a few options, so this seems the simplest to start with:

You could try only applying euler when the state changes AND only when .x > .x * (some value, such as 1.1).  This would provide a more "snap to" kind of approach, something like:

```
 var currentLocation = CGPoint.zero
 var beginLocation = CGPoint.zero

 @objc func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    currentLocation = recognizer.location(in: gameScene)

    var newAngleY = Double(translation.x) * (Double.pi) / 180.0
    newAngleY += self.currentAngle

    switch recognizer.state
    {
     case UIGestureRecognizer.State.began: break
     case UIGestureRecognizer.State.changed:
         if(currentLocation.x > beginLocation.x * 1.1)
         {
           gNodes.bnode.eulerAngles.y = Float(newAngleY)
           beginLocation.x = currentLocation.x
         }
         if(currentLocation.x < beginLocation.x * 0.9) { .etc. }
         break
         case UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended:
           gNodes.bnode.eulerAngles.y = Float(newAngleY)
           break
    }
}
```

Then you could switch to an SCNAction (changing your math) to give more control, such as

```
let vAction = SCNAction.rotateTo(x: 0, y: vAmount, z: 0, duration: 0)
bnode.runAction(vAction)
```